# remove og tag from wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, plugins, action

How can I remove the following tags from the WordPress header?

```
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
```

thanks for your answer`

Comment: The `og` tags aren't core WP, they're added by a plugin.  Check with your plugins and their support.  If you're using Yoast, they have a method to disable the OG tags.

Answer (score 0):

i use php output buffering for resolve this problem:

```
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'on'); // turns on output_buffering
function remove_meta_generators($html)
{

       //edit html of page
        return $html;

}

function clean_meta_generators($html)
{

        ob_start('remove_meta_generators');


}

add_action('get_header', 'clean_meta_generators', 100);
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
    ob_end_flush();
}, 100);
```